# remove gtk2-packages on centos server

Tags: centos, gtk

I recently discovered that gtk2 is installed on my centos server.

because I only connect to the server through PuTTY it's a waste of disk space.

so i just wanted to know what packages should be removed.

Comment: Just `yum erase gtk2` and it'll delete any packages that require it as well.  Only you know what packages you may or may not need.

Comment: FYI it is probably installed with another package. I only installed httpd, mariadb, php, webmin, SPDY xinetd and a group-install with build-tools

Answer (score 1):

GTK2 was installed as dependency of the development tools-group. Since I need the build-tools quite frequently I did not remove them.